# why does a simple print(os.getenv("HOME")) get nil?

Tags: lua, null, environment-variables

I'm a total newbie and I don't get why this doesn't work, anyone knows what's happening?.

I'm following a tutorial and just to clarify, it is only a `print(os.getenv("HOME"))`

Comment: `HOME` is for Linux.  On Windows this env variable has different name: `USERPROFILE`

Comment: Thank you!, didn't know that, I was almost about to try to reinstall Lua :).

Comment: Lua tutorials are written for Linux users )))

Comment: the Lua manual would have told you that os.getenv returns nil for undefined variables. ;)

Comment: You're right, guess I should read it thoroughly. Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How to solve this:

`print(os.getenv("HOME"))` prints `nil`. So `os.getenv("HOME")` must return nil.

In which cases does `os.getenv` return nil? Let's refer to the Lua manual:

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.getenv

> **os.getenv (varname)**
>
> Returns the value of the process environment variable varname or fail
> if the variable is not defined.

`fail` equals `nil`. Lua < 5.4 returns nil.

So looks like `HOME` is an undefined process environment variable.

Should it be defined? What is `HOME` to begin with?

Let's google "environment variable home" and among the first few hits we see:

https://superuser.com/questions/607105/is-the-home-environment-variable-normally-set-in-windows

We are running Windows, otherwise we wouldn't be here in the first place so let's run `print(os.getenv("UserProfile"))` and we have success.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that the accepted answer doesn't mention is that there *is* actually a `$HOME` environment variable in PowerShell, so if you run `echo $HOME` you get `C:\Users\bob` or something. But lua can't see that variable, because `os.getenv("HOME")` looks at the `$Env:HOME` variable which is *not* defined.

If you want to support Windows *and* Linux machines, you can do this:

```lua
print(os.getenv("HOME") or os.getenv("USERPROFILE"))
```

But, if you are going to edit the value in some way, remember the parentheses!

```lua
-- "documents_folder" will be $HOME on Linux, and $Env:USERPROFILE/Documents on Windows
local documents_folder = os.getenv("HOME") or os.getenv("USERPROFILE") .. "/Documents"

-- "documents_folder" will be $HOME/Documents on Linux, and $Env:USERPROFILE/Documents on Windows
local documents_folder = (os.getenv("HOME") or os.getenv("USERPROFILE")) .. "/Documents"
```